# Where is g struct define in golang source code?

Tags: go

In golang source code, there is some code like:

```
MOVL    (g_sched+gobuf_sp)(SI), SP  // sp = m->g0->sched.sp
```

And in `runtime/stubs.go` I found

```
func getg() *g
```

But i can not find `getg` function or `g` struct, where is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The struct is in [`runtime2.go`](https://golang.org/src/runtime/runtime2.go).

> ```
> type g struct {
>   // Stack parameters.
>   // stack describes the actual stack memory: [stack.lo, stack.hi).
>   // stackguard0 is the stack pointer compared in the Go stack growth prologue.
> ```

You can use [`godef`](https://github.com/rogpeppe/godef) to quickly answer questions like that on your own.

The function's comment describes how that works:

> The compiler rewrites calls to this function into instructions
>   that fetch the g directly (from TLS or from the dedicated register).

To see how the compiler does this, check `cmd/compile/internal/gc/typecheck.go`:

> ```
> if ..... && n.Left.Sym.Name == "getg" { ...
> ```

Comment: It is what i want，Thank you！